# One or multiple regression/s?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-encoding

Say your equation in a paper has 6 coefficients, one being your main interest (dummy for *Disability == Having at least one disability*: coded 0/1).

**[image: Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1Age_i + \beta_2Male_i + \beta_3Single_i + \beta_4Educ_i + \beta_5Emp_i +\beta_6Disability_i + \epsilon_i]**

This estimation is done. BUT you want to dig deeper, and study how Disability, by its different types, affects Y (I have dummies for the different types: *motor, visual, hearing, episodic and learning*).

What is the best procedure for this?

Another regression where there are only these dummies? Like this:

[image: Y_i = \rho_0 + \rho_1Motor_i + \rho_2Hearing_i + \rho_3Visual_i + \rho_4Episodic_i + \nu_i]

Or should I estimate the complete model with **Disability + Types of disabilities** and the other 5 variables (*age, gender, education attainment,* etc.)? Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please be more clear: what equation, what 6 coefficients, what is Table 1, what means Table 1 is done, ...?

Comment: Thanks @frank just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Two two regression models answer different questions. The first answers the question, what is the relationship between having any disability and the outcome, holding constant one's age, sex, marital status, education, and employment? The second answers the question, what is the relationship between having specific disabilities and the outcome? The question of which regression is better (i.e., whether to include covariates in either regression) depends on what your research question is.

Why are you including covariates in your first regression? Some of the covariates are confounders and some are mediators, but clearly you have not included all possible confounders and the choice of mediators does not seem to be related to understanding mediation relationships, so what is the goal in fitting such a model? What do you want your regression coefficient to tell you? Why do you want to adjust the coefficients in your first model but not your second?

Regardless of the choice you make, if you want the interpretation of the coefficients to be compatible between the two models, it makes sense to include the same adjustment set in both, especially if you see the second model as a way of disentangling the relationship observed in the first model.